# Can't get to things in tkinter made in class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new in Python and I'm currently trying to use tkinter as first GUI. I was used to making it without classes. And it is my first time to use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `import *`

```
import tkinter as tk

def update():
    pass

#Game.statsFrame #doesn't work Game.statsFrame.stat1_amountLabel too
#Game.stat1_amountLabel #doesnt work < want to use update_idletasks() or 
#just type new cofnig...
#just errors like: "Game' has no attribute 'statsFrame" etc   #Game


class character:
    name = ""
    experience = 0
    level = 0
    gold = 0
    stat1 = 0
    stat2 = 0
    stat3 = 0
    stat4 = 0
    stat5 = 0
    avaiblePoints = 0
    def add_stat1(self):
        if self.avaiblePoints >= 1:
            self.stat1 += 1
            self.avaiblePoints -= 1
            update()
        else:
            pass
    def add_stat2(self):
        if self.avaiblePoints >= 1:
            self.stat2 += 1
            self.avaiblePoints -= 1
            update()
 [...]

myChar = character()
myChar.avaiblePoints = 3

class Game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
    self.myParent = parent
    self.myGame = tk.Frame(parent)
    self.myGame.grid()

    self.statsFrame = tk.Frame(self.myGame).grid()

    self.stat1Label = tk.Label(self.statsFrame)
    self.stat1Label.config(text="Strength:")
    self.stat1Label.grid(column=1, row=1)

    self.stat1_amountLabel = tk.Label(self.statsFrame)
    self.stat1_amountLabel.config(text=myChar.stat1)
    self.stat1_amountLabel.grid(column=2, row=1)

    self.add_stat1Button = tk.Button(self.statsFrame)
    self.add_stat1Button.config(text="+", command=myChar.add_stat1)
    self.add_stat1Button.grid(column=3, row=1)

root = tk.Tk()
myapp = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But I can't get to (for example) `stat1Label` and change text inside it and after it use  `update_idletasks()`. It's like it doesnt exist. Errors shows that `Game` has not atributtes like stat1Label etc.

I want to use it becouse I have read that `__init__` method is better and I want to swtich between pages. I have no idea, when I wasn't using class in tkinter some things (like this) was easier and had no problems. I'm very confused guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's excellent that you're using `import tkinter as tk` instead of the dreaded "star" import, and that you're trying to organize your code with classes. It can be a little confusing at first, but it makes your code more modular, which helps enormously, especially when the GUI gets large.

There are a few problems with your code. The most important one is this line:

```
self.statsFrame = tk.Frame(self.myGame).grid()
```

The `.grid` method (and `.pack` and `.place`) all return `None`. So that line saves `None` to `self.statsFrame`, not the Frame widget. So when you later try to do stuff with `self.statsFrame` it won't do what you expect.

Another problem is that the `text` attribute of your `self.stat1_amountLabel` doesn't track the value of `myChar.stat1`, so when you change the value of `myChar.stat1` you need to explicitly update the Label with the new value. Alternatively, you *could* use the `textvariable` attribute with an [`IntVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to hold the character's stat. See the entry for `textvariable` in the [`Label` config docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) for info.

Your `character` class has a whole bunch of attributes like `name`, `experience` etc as class attributes. That's not a good idea because class attributes are shared by all instances of a class. But you probably want each character instance to have their own instance attributes. So you should give `character` an `__init__` method where you set those attributes. OTOH, it's ok to use class attributes for default values that get overridden by instance attributes.

Anyway, here's a repaired version of your code with a Button that updates the Strength stat. I've put the stats in a list, rather than having a bunch of separate named stats that would have to be managed separately. And I've given `Game` a `make_stat` method so you can easily add rows for the other stats.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Character:
    def __init__(self, availablePoints=0):
        self.name = ""
        self.experience = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.gold = 0
        self.stats = [0] * 5
        self.availablePoints = availablePoints

    def add_stat(self, idx):
        if self.availablePoints >= 1:
            self.stats[idx] += 1
            self.availablePoints -= 1

class Game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.myGame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myGame.grid()

        self.statsFrame = tk.Frame(self.myGame)
        self.statsFrame.grid()

        self.make_stat("Strength:", 0, 0)

    def make_stat(self, text, idx, row):
        label = tk.Label(self.statsFrame, text=text)
        label.grid(column=1, row=row)

        amount = tk.Label(self.statsFrame, text=myChar.stats[idx])
        amount.grid(column=2, row=row)

        def update():
            myChar.add_stat(idx)
            amount["text"] = myChar.stats[idx]

        button = tk.Button(self.statsFrame, text="+", command=update)
        button.grid(column=3, row=row)

myChar = Character(3)

root = tk.Tk()
myapp = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code is still not ideal, but it's an improvement. ;) For example, it would be good to give `Game` a method for creating new characters, rather than creating them in the global context. You could store them in a `dict` attribute of `Game`, using the character's name as the key.

---

Here's a new version that works on separate named `stat` attributes. As I said in the comments, doing it this way is more complicated (and less efficient) than using a list to hold the stats.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Character:
    def __init__(self, availablePoints):
        self.name = ""
        self.experience = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.gold = 0
        self.stat1 = 0
        self.stat2 = 0
        self.stat3 = 0
        self.stat4 = 0
        self.stat5 = 0
        self.availablePoints = availablePoints

class Game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.myGame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myGame.grid()

        self.statsFrame = tk.Frame(self.myGame)
        self.statsFrame.grid()

        self.make_stat("Strength:", "stat1", 1, 1)

    def make_stat(self, text, stat, column, row):
        label = tk.Label(self.statsFrame, text=text)
        label.grid(column=column, row=row)

        amount = tk.Label(self.statsFrame, text=getattr(myChar, stat))
        amount.grid(column=(column+1), row=row)

        def update():
            if myChar.availablePoints >= 1:
                v = getattr(myChar, stat) + 1
                setattr(myChar, stat, v)
                myChar.availablePoints -= 1
                amount["text"] = v

        button = tk.Button(self.statsFrame, text="+", command=update)
        button.grid(column=(column+2), row=row)

myChar = Character(5)

root = tk.Tk()
myapp = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I haven't seen any diffrence between `text` and `textvariable`, both were working. I have to understand some things in this code, `__init__` method is weird sometimes for me. And again, thanks for help.

Comment: Hello, I made some changes to be more clear for me and now I have question: here is changed code - https://pastebin.com/jShKUZRD , I want to make add/update function in class `make_stat` but I don't know how to get parametr `stat` from `make_stat` to function `update` (`update` 's name is invalid right know)

Comment: @KrystianGrzelak It's _not_ a good idea to have separate `stat1`, `stat2`, etc, attributes. It's much better to put them in a list, or maybe a dictionary. By getting rid of my `Character.stats` list and `Character.add_stat` method you've actually made the logic more complicated. My `update` function is local to the `Game.make_stat` method: it's only defined inside that method, so you can't call it from outside `Game.make_stat`. It's _possible_ to do what you want, but I don't think it's a good idea. But I'll add a new version to my answer that shows how to do it.

Comment: I don't want waste your time, you have helped me a lot. Thank you again for tips.It helped me understand some new cool things.

Comment: @KrystianGrzelak No worries. But if you have further questions about this game, please ask a fresh question. You can link to it in a comment here if you want.

Comment: Ohh, just give me simple answer. If I want make equipment system (helmets, armor, weapons etc.) I have to make class/object called `items`, then put it into `character`? I want to make for them 3 methods - `takeOn`, `takeOff` and `sell`. It is good idea? Put them into `character` as a list?

Comment: @KrystianGrzelak Yes, you could put them into `character` as a list. Or  you could use a dict, so you can store the name of each type of equpment and the number of items of each type.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5EunrGx7 I have probably used your tips, what do you think about this simple equipment system?